# Asymptote: intersection points of unit circle with polygon returns less points

Tags: asymptote

I have the following code:

```
unitsize(1cm);
path c = circle( (0,0), 1 );
path p(int sides) {return polygon(sides);}

int sides = 3;

for(sides; sides <= 8; ++sides){
    path pol = shift( (2.2sides,0) )*p(sides);
    path cir = shift(2.2sides,0)*c;
    pair vert[] = intersectionpoints( pol , cir );
    draw(pol);
    draw(cir);
    for(int k = 0; k <= vert.length-1; ++k){
        dot(vert[k], L = string(k), fontsize(8pt) );
    }
}

path icos = shift( 2.2(sides) )*polygon(20);
path cir = shift( 2.2(sides) )*unitcircle;
pair vert[] = intersectionpoints( icos, cir );
for(int k = 0; k <= vert.length-1; ++k){
    dot(vert[k]);
}
draw(icos);
draw(cir);
```

This produces the attached picture; notice that for an odd number of sides, it only computes one intersection point. What I want is to draw the intersection points of a polygon with its circumcircle; note that for the last one, the icosahedron, I used `unitcircle` instead of `circle`, just to be sure I got the same result.

My Asymptote version is 2.65, and my Ghostscript version is 9.52; both packaged in the Debian TeXLive 2019 distribution.

How can I get all the intersection points of a regular polygon with its circumcircle? Thanks in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Upon reading the documentation I found the routine `Circle`, of the module `graph`, with which "a true circle can be produced" (page 31). Using this solves the problem.

```
settings.outformat="pdf";
unitsize(1cm);
import graph;

path c = Circle( (0,0), 1 );
path p(int sides) {return polygon(sides);}

int sides = 3;

for(sides; sides <= 8; ++sides){
    path pol = shift( (2.2sides,0) )*p(sides);
    path cir = shift(2.2sides,0)*c;
    pair vert[] = intersectionpoints( pol , cir );
    draw(pol);
    draw(cir);
    for(int k = 0; k <= vert.length-1; ++k){
        dot(vert[k], L = string(k), fontsize(8pt) );
    }
}

path icos = shift( 2.2(sides) )*polygon(20);
path cir = shift( 2.2(sides) )*c;
pair vert[] = intersectionpoints( icos, cir );
for(int k = 0; k <= vert.length-1; ++k){
    dot(vert[k], L=string(k), fontsize(4pt));
}
draw(icos);
draw(cir);

path Ellipse(pair centre = (0,0), real xradius, real yradius){
    return shift( ( centre ) )*scale( xradius, yradius )*Circle( (0,0), 1);
}

path elip = shift( 2.2(sides+1) )*Ellipse( (0,0), 1.1, 0.8 );
path cir1 = shift( 2.2(sides+1) )*c;
draw(elip);
draw(cir1);
pair verts[] = intersectionpoints( elip, cir1 );
for(int k = 0; k <= verts.length-1;++k){
    dot(verts[k], L=string(k), fontsize(4pt));
}
```

[image]

Comment: Very useful question and answer, +1 to both.

Comment: Much obliged! Do you know why this happens?

Comment: No. But from your answer I take that the unreal circle is just a collection of Bezier curves which do not precisely match an exact circle, and thus the intersections are not found.

Comment: Apparently so: on page 12 of the documentation you can read the definition `path unitcircle=E..N..W..S..cycle;`; it says it is accurate within 0.06%.

Comment: The intersection points are the vertices of the polygon. Even with `Circle` function such a behavior (missing intersection points) or having two points may happen depending on the numerical precision and the points which define the circle. Similar situations may happen with two tangent paths. It is due to the numerical method and/or the machine precision.

Comment: You can also ask to have a precision bigger than the precision machine by `intersectionpoints( pol , cir,0.001 );` (try 0.00001). It illustrates the problem of determining points with approximations.

Comment: Consider using something like
`L = Label(string(k),align=shift(-2.2(sides) )*vert[k])`
for better alignment of the labels.

Comment: @g.kov I used `L = Label(string(k), align = 1.1exit )` where `exit = expi(2pi*k/sides[l])`, so the labe appears in the direction of the vertex.

Comment: Then you can replace the image with the new one, where the numbers are placed properly.